# tkinter buttons shrink to fit frame

Tags: python, button, tkinter, autoresize

Is there a way to ensure buttons shrink to fit the tkinter frame.

Here is what my code is.

```
import tkinter as tk
import dashboard as da
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Dashboard(): 
    def __init__(self, root):
        global colors
        self.root=root
        root.title("NATT SERVER DASHBOARD VIEW")

        headerPanel = tk.Frame(root, background=colors["grey2"], width=800, height=100)
        accountPanel = tk.Frame(headerPanel, background=colors["grey3"], width=100, height=100)
        infoPanel = tk.Frame(headerPanel, background=colors["grey1"], bd=2, width=800, height=50)
        buttonPanel = tk.Frame(root, background=colors["grey2"], width=100, height=700)
        canvasPanel = tk.Frame(root, background=colors["white"], width=700, height=700)

        # pack these panels
        accountPanel.pack(side="left",fill="both")
        infoPanel.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        headerPanel.pack(fill="x")
        canvasPanel.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)
        buttonPanel.pack(side="left", fill="y")

        self._user_account(accountPanel)
        self._create_header(headerPanel)
        self._create_info_panel(infoPanel)
        self._create_buttons(buttonPanel)
        self._create_canvas(canvasPanel)

    def _create_buttons(self, parent):  #======================{{{
        global colors
        img = Image.open("icons/server-status-icon-100x100.png")
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        b1=tk.Button(parent, image=photo, bg=colors["grey1"], command=self._server_status)
        b1.image = photo
        b1.pack(side="top", anchor = "n")

        img = Image.open("icons/application-icon-100x100.png")
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        b2=tk.Button(parent, image=photo, bg=colors["grey1"], command=lambda: self._contents("black", "version.log"))
        b2.image = photo
        b2.pack(side="top", anchor = "n")

        img = Image.open("icons/clean-up-icon-100x100.png")
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        b3=tk.Button(parent, image=photo, bg=colors["grey1"], command=lambda: self._contents("black", "cleanup_03_07_2015_18_05_15.jag"))
        b3.image = photo
        b3.pack(side="top", anchor = "n")

        img = Image.open("icons/log-display-icon-100x100.png")
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        b4=tk.Button(parent, image=photo, bg=colors["grey1"], command=self._log_display)
        b4.image = photo
        b4.pack(side="top", anchor = "n")

        img = Image.open("icons/link-status-icon-100x100.png")
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        b5=tk.Button(parent, image=photo, bg=colors["grey1"], command=self._link_status)
        b5.image = photo
        b5.pack(side="top", anchor = "n")

        img = Image.open("icons/defect-resolution-icon-100x100.png")
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        b6=tk.Button(parent, image=photo, bg=colors["grey1"], command=lambda: self._contents("black", "version.log"))
        b6.image = photo
        b6.pack(side="top", anchor = "n")

        img = Image.open("icons/app-process-icon-100x100.png")
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        b7=tk.Button(parent, image=photo, bg=colors["grey1"], command=self._process_output)
        b7.image = photo
        b7.pack(side="top", anchor = "n")


if __name__== '__main__':
    root=tk.Tk()
    board=Dashboard(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Images as you see are 100X100 png images.

The issue is, when the frame appears last two buttons doesn't appear in frame. If I resize complete window, buttons at bottom doesn't appear. Is there a way to dynamically resize the buttons when the main window resize.
tried with google with all available options , e.g pack.propagate, and others, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

No, tkinter can't automatically shrink buttons to fit inside a frame. You will have to manage all of that yourself. You can, for instance, add a binding to the `<Configure>` event of the frame, which gets called whenever the frame changes size. You can then get the size of the frame and iterate over the children, doing whatever you need to do to get things to fit.

Comment: @jagpreet: no, sorry. i've never seen anyone try it. It won't be easy because tkinter can't scale images except by factors of two. To do anything more requires other libraries. It should be possible, but I have doubts that it would be worth the effort. The easier solution would be to create two or three sizes of icons that your app can swap in and out.

Comment: well, I need to rework on whole frame again. I have other ideas though but was trying for a shortcut if available.  I'm glad to receive your expert inputs again. Thank you.